# How to include missing values in subsetting observations in dataframe in R?

Tags: r, subset, missing-data, data-extraction

I wanted to include participants who rated 1 on a question AND those who did not respond to the question (ie. "NA"). I've tried to use the subsetting function in R but the number of participants returned is zero in many codes I tried. Below is the code I used. I think the first part of the code "alldata$Debrief_2=='1'" is correct because when I entered it alone, it always returned with a reasonable number of participants.

But for the second part (i.e, "is.na(alldata$Debrief_2)"), which is about the missing values, the figure returned is always zero across the attempts I made. So I reckon the main problem lies with the code for the missing values.

```
alldata3 <- alldata[ which(alldata$Debrief_2=='1'
& (is.na(alldata$Debrief_2))
), ]
```

I've also tried the following codes to include the missing values, but the results were all zero observations.

```
alldata3 <- alldata[ which(alldata$Debrief_2=='1'

+                            & is.na(alldata$Debrief_2)

+                                    ), ]
```

```
alldata3 <- alldata[ which(alldata$Debrief_2=='1'

+                            & alldata$Debrief_2=='is.na'

+                                    ), ]
```

```
alldata3 <- alldata[ which(alldata$Debrief_2!='2'

+                           ),na.rm=TRUE]
```

It is weird to me that the is.na didn't work because when I checked for missing values using the code below, it returned a reasonable number of observations of missing values. I also did not change anything in the empty columns in the excel I imported to R (ie., I did not change the NA to character).

```
sum(is.na(alldata$Debrief_2))
```

I've also tried excluding participants who rated 2 (there are only two options of the answer 1 or 2), but the result is the same as including only participants who rated 1. Please see the code below.

```
 alldata3 <- alldata[ which(alldata$Debrief_2!='2'

+                           ), ]
```

I've read the string below and I've used the code suggested but as you can see, it didn't work in my case...:(

https://www.edureka.co/community/2308/how-to-subset-rows-containing-in-chosen-column-of-data-frame

**
Would someone please suggest a correct code for me to include participants with missing values? Thank you for your help in advance!**

Comment: What does this mean - `\<-` ?

Comment: Sorry it is a typo. the slash is not meant to be there. I did not include the slash in my original code as well. It should appear as <-

Comment: Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74719329/edit) your post.

Answer (score 0):

As you did not include a reproducible example, I made up some data.

```
# data
set.seed(22)
all_data <- data.frame("Debrief_1" = sample(c(NA, 1:10), 100, replace = TRUE), 
                       "Debrief_2" = sample(c(NA, 1:10), 100, replace = TRUE))
```

We may then subset using **or**, i.e., we want to keep the observation **if** Debrief_1" is equal to 1 or NA.

```
# subset
with(all_data, 
     {all_data[Debrief_1 == 1 | is.na(Debrief_1), ]})

#    Debrief_1 Debrief_2
# 6         NA         4
# 14        NA        NA
# 16         1         5
# 17        NA         9
# 21        NA         2
# 34        NA         5
# 35         1        NA
# 36        NA         8
# 38         1         7
# 39         1         7
# 52         1         6
# 54        NA         7
# 61        NA         2
# 70        NA         6
# 71         1         8
# 83         1         2
# 84         1         2
# 90        NA        NA
# 93        NA         5
```

Comment: Hi @fabla, thank you so much for your prompt response and help! I've used your code and it worked!!! You are awesome!! Thank you for creating the data manually as well. I'll remember to provide a dataset in my future post. Thank you again!!! :D